# How to fix this typeError getting during installation of a theme

Tags: installation, typeerror, web-hosting

I am trying install a theme in [Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com/?ppc_campaign=google_search_brand&bidkw=hostinger&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8smr8oOagQMVTsbjBx1QbAk-EAAYASAAEgLj6PD_BwE).

When I proceed for installation using the [link](https://crispyprompts.com/installer/script), I get the following error:

```
TypeError

Carbon\\Carbon::setLastErrors(): Argument #1 ($lastErrors) must be of type array, bool given, called in /home/u984601026/domains/crispyprompts.com/public_html/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php on line 98
```

How can I fix this error and install the theme? Since I don't have any coding knowledge. Please guide me.